# Comparing 2 text files with different content in java (for each lines in text1 need to compare to each line in text2)

Tags: java, file, loops

I am trying to compare two .txt files (their contents), but when I execute this code my application goes into one time loop. I want to compare line by line. For example, in first.txt, I have 4 lines and in second.txt i have 10 lines. I want to compare this (from first.txt): `0   111   1` with `0   111   1`(second.txt) and `0   112  1`(second.txt). As you see, they have different value, but same source and target.
So, from first.txt I can compare with second.txt more than 1 time.

Anybody can correct my mistake,please?

This is file that I mean:
First.txt

```
source value target
0   111     1
0   222     2
0   333     3
0   444     4
```

Second.txt

```
source value target
0   111     1
0   222     2
0   333     3
0   444     4
1   555     1
2   987     1
0   112     1
0   223     2
0   334     3
0   445     4
```

Here is my code:

```
        // create new reader for cs
        frCs = new FileReader("nodeCsArr.txt");
        lnrCs = new LineNumberReader(frCs);

        // create new reader for rs
        frRs = new FileReader("nodeRsArr.txt");
        lnRs = new LineNumberReader(frRs);

        System.out.println("------Read distance Current State-----");
        // read distance on Cs
        while((strCs=lnrCs.readLine())!=null){
            i=lnrCs.getLineNumber(); 
            //edited here
            System.out.println("snCs baris ke-: "+i);

            stateArray=strCs.split("\t");

            //kolomnya
            snCs= stateArray[0]; System.out.println("snCs: "+snCs);
            dCs= stateArray[1]; //System.out.println("dCs: "+dCs);
            tnCs = stateArray[2]; 
            NodeLength=dCs.length(); System.out.println("panjang= "+NodeLength);

            System.out.println("------Read distance Random State-----");
            // read distance on Rs
            if((strRs=lnRs.readLine())!=null){
                i=lnRs.getLineNumber();
                //edited here
                System.out.println("snRs baris ke-: "+i);

                stateArray=strRs.split("\t");

                //input array--starts opencl here
                snRs= stateArray[0]; System.out.println("snRs: "+snRs);
                dRs= stateArray[1]; //System.out.println("dRs: "+dRs);
                tnRs = stateArray[2];  

                if ((snCs.equals(snRs))&&(tnCs.equals(tnRs))) {
                    System.out.println("snCs= "+snCs+" tnCs= "+tnCs+" dcs= "+dCs);
                    System.out.println("snRs= "+snRs+" tnRs= "+tnRs+" drs= "+dRs);
                    dTot=0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < NodeLength; j++) {

                        if (dCs.toCharArray()[j]==dRs.toCharArray()[j]) {
                            difBit=0;    
                        }else{
                            difBit=1;
                        }
                        dTot=dTot+difBit;
                    }   
                    dist=dTot/NodeLength;
                    System.out.println("different bit= "+dTot);
                    System.out.println("distance= "+dist);  
                }
            }
        }
        //lnRs.close();

        lnrCs.close();`
```

Comment: Could you provide your 2 files and point out there what you want? Because it's not clear from your question

Comment: yes, I added in my question. Is it more clear now?

Comment: So and what's now going on exactly? Do you know every time which file is the 'longer' one? So if the all the lines of A (20 lines) are exactly the same as the first 20 lines of file B, then you say the are the same? And what you mean by one time loop ;)?

Comment: Do you wan to compare line1 in A with only line one in B?

Comment: I'll posted a possible solution. Just to tell you it really depends on your definition of equality.

Comment: @robin, not like that, I want to compare line1 in A with line 1 and line 21 in B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. I just read the the first file (does not matter if the 'longer' or 'shorter' one) line by line in an ArrayList

Then I'll go line by line through the second file and compare those lines.

first.txt:

```
0   111
0   222
0   333
0   444
```

second.txt:

```
0   111
0   222
0   333
0   444
1   555
2   987
```

Here the code (for simpicity just in the main method:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CompareFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean same = true;
        Scanner in = null;

        try {
            in = new Scanner(new FileReader("first.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayList<String> firstLines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            firstLines.add(in.nextLine());
        }
        in.close();

        try {
            in = new Scanner(new FileReader("second.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int counter = 0;
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            if (counter < firstLines.size()) {
                if (!((in.nextLine()).equals(firstLines.get(counter)))) {
                    same = false;
                    break;
                }
                counter++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        in.close();
        System.out.println(same);
    }
}
```

Remember, I'm just checking from if the files are the same, starting from the beginning of a file.
So:
A
A
and
A
B
A
A
would not be the same. It really depends on how you define equality.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But This is not that i mean. I edit again my question, could you please read it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Scanner to read every line, i.e:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
(...)
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = stdin.nextLine();
```

Compare them in two loops (1. every line in A, 2. every line in B) - get 1st line from A and compare to every B line until reach lineB.length, then get 2nd line frm A and compare to every line from B, get next line from A...